# Ubuntu Windows Azure mass storage

Tags: virtual-machines, storage, azure

I just started using Windows Azure service. I created an XL machine, and I got 28GB on the primary partition and a whopping 600GB on the temporary partition.

My application needs a lot more space than those 28GB of data. Is it possible to convert those temporary 600GB in something persistent between reboots? If yes how?

Comment: I believe you can have up to 128GB on `C:` using an XL Azure instance. If there a reason you chose 28GB instead of 128GB?

Comment: I created the VM, but I don't remember this particular. If I did (I can't exclude it) is there a way to modify this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to create additional durable disks in Windows Azure that will get saved to Azure Blog storage, persiste between reboots, and can be disconnected and reconnected to any machine.

Instructions on it can be found [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/), but it basically involves creating a VHD, uploading it to blob storage, attaching it in the web config and then configuring it on your server.